# Why does my julia code run so slowly?

Tags: performance, julia

```
redim = 2;
# Loading data
iris_data = readdlm("iris_data.csv");
iris_target = readdlm("iris_target.csv");

# Center data
iris_data = broadcast(-, iris_data, mean(iris_data, 1));
n_data, n_dim = size(iris_data);

Sw = zeros(n_dim, n_dim);
Sb = zeros(n_dim, n_dim);

C = cov(iris_data);


classes = unique(iris_target);

for i=1:length(classes)
    index = find(x -> x==classes[i], iris_target);
    d = iris_data[index,:];
    classcov = cov(d);
    Sw += length(index) / n_data .* classcov;
end
Sb = C - Sw;

evals, evecs = eig(Sw, Sb);
w = evecs[:,1:redim];
new_data = iris_data * w;
```

This code just does LDA (linear discriminant analysis) for the iris_data.
Reduct the dimensions of the iris_data to 2. 
It will takes about 4 seconds, but Python(numpy/scipy) only takes about 0.6 seconds.
 Why?

Comment: worth reading the [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/).

Comment: You don't need all those semicolons `;` in Julia.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is from the first page, second paragraph of the introduction in the [Julia Manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/):

> Because Julia’s compiler is different from the interpreters used for languages like Python or R, you may find that Julia’s performance is unintuitive at first. If you find that something is slow, we highly recommend reading through the **[Performance Tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/)** section before trying anything else. Once you understand how Julia works, it’s easy to write code that’s nearly as fast as C.

---

Excerpt:

> ### Avoid global variables
>
> A global variable might have its value, and therefore its type, change at any point. This makes it difficult for the compiler to optimize code using global variables. Variables should be local, or passed as arguments to functions, whenever possible.
>
> Any code that is performance critical or being benchmarked should be inside a function.
>
> We find that global names are frequently constants, and declaring them as such greatly improves performance

---

Knowing that the *script* (all procedural top level code) style is so pervasive among many scientific computing users, I would recommend you to at least wrap the whole file inside a `let` expression for starters (let introduces a new local scope), ie:

```rb
let

redim = 2
# Loading data
iris_data = readdlm("iris_data.csv")
iris_target = readdlm("iris_target.csv")

# Center data
iris_data = broadcast(-, iris_data, mean(iris_data, 1))
n_data, n_dim = size(iris_data)

Sw = zeros(n_dim, n_dim)
Sb = zeros(n_dim, n_dim)

C = cov(iris_data)


classes = unique(iris_target)

for i=1:length(classes)
    index = find(x -> x==classes[i], iris_target)
    d = iris_data[index,:]
    classcov = cov(d)
    Sw += length(index) / n_data .* classcov
end
Sb = C - Sw

evals, evecs = eig(Sw, Sb)
w = evecs[:,1:redim]
new_data = iris_data * w

end
```

But I would also urge you to refactor that into small functions and then compose a `main` function that calls the rest, something like this, notice how this refactor makes your code general and reusable (and fast):

```rb
module LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

export load_data, center_data

"Returns data and target Matrices."
load_data(data_path, target_path) = (readdlm(data_path), readdlm(target_path))

function center_data(data, target)
    data = broadcast(-, data, mean(data, 1))
    n_data, n_dim = size(data)
    Sw = zeros(n_dim, n_dim)
    Sb = zeros(n_dim, n_dim)
    C = cov(data)
    classes = unique(target)
    for i=1:length(classes)
        index = find(x -> x==classes[i], target)
        d = data[index,:]
        classcov = cov(d)
        Sw += length(index) / n_data .* classcov
    end
    Sb = C - Sw
    evals, evecs = eig(Sw, Sb)
    redim = 2
    w = evecs[:,1:redim]
    return data * w
end

end
```

---

```rb
using LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

function main()
    iris_data, iris_target = load_data("iris_data.csv", "iris_target.csv")
    result = center_data(iris_data, iris_target)
    @show result
end

main()
```

Notes:

- You don't need all those semicolons.
- anonymous functions are currently slow but that will change in v0.5. You can use [FastAnonymous](https://github.com/timholy/FastAnonymous.jl) for now, if performance is critical.
- In summary read carefully and take into account **all** the performance tips.
- `main` is just a name, it could be anything else you like.

Comment: is there any difference between using a `main` function and using a `let` block, or is it just "best practice"? what about declaring some variables as `const` like `iris_data`? I often find myself declaring data I want to compute on as `const` given that "the script style is so pervasive among many scientific computing users" :P

Comment: **Thank you so much!**

Comment: The difference is that it's best practice indeed! :D Declaring global variables as `const` would also work, but then you loose the modularity (useful for testing, profiling and benchmarking without falling into [confounding](http://zedshaw.com/archive/programmers-need-to-learn-statistics-or-i-will-kill-them-all)) of using modules and functions to reuse the code with n different datasets, the functionality of `center_data` does not and should not depend on `iris_data.csv` & `iris_target.csv` for example, those are just parameters fed to the function instead, making it reusable not disposable.